# How to put a partially transparent image above another image in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, opacity

I want to place an image above another image so that when I make my second image partially transparent first image will be seen. But I do not want to use background image for first image as

```
 <div style="background-image: url("firstImage.png");">
    <img src="secondImage.png"/>
 </div>
```

as it is much obvious. Is there any technique to put another image on first image without making first image as background image.

Comment: Can you share the images please?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are looking for based on your description, but it sounds like what you are looking for could be replicated by using css positioning to place one image over the other (probably absolute or relative positioning in your case)

Comment: @Frondor You can consider any two images but I will change the opacity of  image which is above first image so that first image will be seen also.

Comment: In simple i think, you have to keep two placeholder for 2 images. Make both the containers with absolute position, so one comes above. Keep the parent as relative positioned . Then you can change the opacity of the second image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were going to use css for this.  The `position` statement allows for `absolute` and `relative` positioning.

By setting `position:absolute` we can position the element relative to the document's (0,0).  Then you can use `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` to further position the element relative to those edges.

`position:relative` is similar to the default positioning of HTML elements. However, by adding `position:relative` to the parent of an `absolute` positioned element, we force it to use the partent's (0,0), rather then the document's.

```css
.layered-image {
  position: relative;
}
.layered-image img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
.image-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  opacity: .4
}
```

```html
<div class="layered-image">
  <img class="image-base" src="http://digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/flickr/5661878892_15fba42846_o.jpg" alt=""/>
  <img class="image-overlay" src="https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/city-wallpaper-47.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

A side note: While `z-index` can be useful, i try to avoid it whenever possible. It causes some nasty bugs in the latest versions of webkit, especially safari's implementation in iOS.  If you order your html elements properly, there is no need for using `z-index`.  Except of course, when you must.

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
 <div class="imageWrapper" style="position: relative; width: 195px; height: 195px;">
   <img src="firstImage.png" alt=.. width=.. height=..style="position: relative; z-index: 1;" />
   <img src="secondImage.png" alt=.. width=.. height=.. style="position: absolute;left:80px; top: 80px;z-index: 10;" />
 </div>
```

for more solutions check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996776/position-a-image-over-another-existing-img-in-css).

Comment: It is not about ". Background image is clearly visible through partially transparent secondImage.png placed using IMG tag. THat is only given for a reference. However, I do not want to [place first image in any element as background image.

Comment: I have edited my ans , hope this helps . I have added the link from where I have taken reference .

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link

http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

You will get what you want by using simple css changes & opacity feature

Answer (score 0):

Put the image tags in the container, and first make the positions to absolute afterwards set the z-index property of back or front image then set the ocupacy of the image.

```css
            img {
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     position: absolute;
   }
   
   img.front {
     z-index: 2 opacity: 0.6;
     filter: alpha(opacity=60);
   }
   
   img.back {
     z-index: 1
   }
```

```html
  <div>
  <img class="back" src="http://all4desktop.com/data_images/original/4237684-images.jpg" />
  <img class="front" src="http://www.hdwallpapery.com/static/images/creativity_water_spray_drops_flower_rose_desktop_images_TVIdSpG.jpg" />

</div>
```